# OSX API Question: Where does BlockZero live?

Tags: api, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to compile a program I've been working with on OSX 10.6
It compiles fine under 10.5 but now I get an undeclared error for something called BlockZero.

I'm not sure what this function is, what it does or where it lives. 
What do I have to import to fix this?

Some Googling suggests it might be part of Carbon. Is there a particular framework I can link against?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else runs into this: BlockZero is a function that seems to zero a block of memory. It lives in CoreServices and is defined in MacMemory.h.
The problem is that the function is unavailable to apps being compiled as 64bit (which is the default; hence my problem). To fix this issue use the BSD function bzero.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/OtherAPIChanges/OtherAPIChanges.html